# How can I get the exact value from the IPL function?

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct treeNode {
    int key;
    struct treeNode* left;
    struct treeNode* right;
} treeNode;


int count = 0;

treeNode* insertNode(treeNode** t1, int x) {
    if (*t1 == NULL) {
        *t1 = malloc(sizeof(treeNode));
        (*t1)->key = x;
        (*t1)->left = NULL;
        (*t1)->right = NULL;
    }
    else if (x < (*t1)->key) {  //left
        (*t1)->left = insertNode(&(*t1)->left, x);
    }
    else if (x > (*t1)->key) { //right
        (*t1)->right = insertNode(&(*t1)->right, x);
    }
    else {
        printf("SameValue exist.\n");
    }
    return *t1;
}

int getIPL(treeNode* n1) {
    int rightcount;
    int leftcount;
    int rootcount = 1;

    if (n1 != NULL) {
        if (n1->left == NULL && n1->right == NULL) {
            count = rootcount;
        }
        else if (n1->left != NULL && n1->right == NULL) {
            leftcount = 1 + getIPL(n1->left);
            count += leftcount;
        }
        else if (n1->left == NULL && n1->right != NULL) {
            rightcount = 1 + getIPL(n1->right);
            count += rightcount;
        }
        else {
            leftcount = 1 + getIPL(n1->left);
            rightcount = 1 + getIPL(n1->right);
            count += leftcount + rightcount;
        }
    }
    return count;
}


int main() {
    treeNode* T1 = NULL;

    insertNode(&T1, 10);
    insertNode(&T1, 20);
    insertNode(&T1, 3);
    insertNode(&T1, 25);

    printf("IPL : %d", getIPL(T1));
}
```

This code is to get an internal path length (IPL) from BST.
It works normally up to level 2, but it doesn't work above that.

When put on tree 10 5 15, IPL value of 5 comes out.

After, put on 30, you will get 9, not the normal value 8.

I want the IPL value of 8.

Please tell me where the problem is.

Comment: You need to show a [mcve] along with input and expected vs. actual output.

Comment: Where is `count` declared and initialized?

Comment: Sorry, I edited it and uploaded it again.

Comment: @Ian Abbott It's a global variable

Comment: The calls to `insertNode()` from `main()` look wrong. Shouldn't `T1` be initialized to `NULL`, and shouldn't the address of `T1` be passed to `insertNode`?

Comment: @Ian Abbott Sorry, I fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The depth of each node needs to be taken into account. For example:

```
static int getIPL_helper(treeNode *n1, int depth) {
    if (n1) {
        return getIPL_helper(n1->left, depth + 1) +
               getIPL_helper(n1->right, depth + 1) + depth;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

int getIPL(treeNode *n1) {
    return getIPL_helper(n1, 1);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I have a question. What do you think I missed?

Comment: @Hyeonbinshin I'm not sure exactly where you went wrong, but setting the global `count` variable to 1 every time you reach a childless node probably doesn't help! Recursive functions and global variables usually do not mix well.

Comment: Thank you for your help.
Is it because of the stack overflow that the global variable is not used well for recursive functions?

Comment: No it is nothing to do with stack overflow. You need to be careful how global variables are used, if a recursive call changes a global variable in a way that wrecks the overall calculation. That also applies when passing a pointer to some state variable used by all the recursive calls.